# React "lifting state up" philosophie : How to avoid ending up with one big parent component containing all the code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns

This is not a very precise question. I think I understand the "react lifting state up" paradigm. As far as I know, this is the only clean way for two sibling components to have access to their respective properties.

But doing so, I end up with one tremendous class containing everything : the data information for the properties of all of its child components, and all the functions in charge of updating this information (in charge of calling `setState`). I'm unhappy with the fact that I'm not able anymore to dispatch into sub-components, the work that has to do with them.

My question is : how to avoid the concentration of all the code in parent components, using react, while keeping the nice clean state/prop mechanism ? Or am I wrong to complain maybe ?

Comment: Think of it as Lifting state 'enough'. Only raise state to the point at which necessary sharing of state can happen. That will sometimes be the top of the app, but not always.

Comment: Lifting up state to the root component is not a good idea. Lift up state when it is necessary. I think with redux library managing state is easier because component can connect to redux store to get data. You can also update store by dispatch an action.

Comment: ["We recommend lifting the shared state up to their _closest common ancestor_"](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). The "closest common ancestor" part is important, as lifting the state up higher than that would be very cumbersome, like you said.

Answer (score 2):

Many people believe jumping directly into redux would be a good idea, but in fact, it comes with lots of computational overhead and boilerplate code.

As a rule of thumb, you would simply move logic up the tree which is relevant not only for child components but also for siblings.

You should also have a look at the concept of [Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).